# Why function is not updating with `useCallback` in React and Chart.js

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

**Background**: I'm using React and chart.js to display a bar chart. I'm using also the `chartjs-plugin-dragdata` and `chartjs-plugin-zoom` to drag and zoom my chart within certain limits.

**What I'm trying to do**: in the dragdata plugin there is the option to modify the `onDragStart` and `onDragEnd` functions with custom ones (doc: https://github.com/chrispahm/chartjs-plugin-dragdata) within the options object. I want to change this function whenever a certain state is updated. The state is updated in another component and I can listen to its change via the `useEffect` hook.

```
// works when setActiveState is called
useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(activeState) // changes from state_1 to state_2
}, [activeState]);
```

And in the actual code:

```
export const SomeComponent: FC = () => {
    const { activeState } = useContext(CertainContext)
    const data = //.. some data

    const onDragStart = (event, elIndex, chartIndex)=> {
        console.log(activeState) // <-- here I have the issue, always state_1
    }
    const options = {
        // other options
        plugins: {
            dragData: {
                onDragStart: onDragStart
            }
        }
    }
    return (
      <Chart
        type="bar"
        options={options}
        data={data}
      />
    )
}
```

The issue is that no matter what I try, the `onDragStart` function seems to "save" the first `activeState` value and never modifies or updates it.

**What I tried**: From my understanding it has to do with how react closes around values in functions, therefore I tried also to use the `useCallback` hook to recompute the function whenever the `activeState` changes, without success.

```
export const SomeComponent: FC = () => {
    const { activeState } = useContext(CertainContext)
    const data = //.. some data

    const onDragStart = useCallback((event, elIndex, chartIndex)=> {
        console.log(activeState) // <-- here I have the issue, always state_1
    }, [activeState])
    const options = {
        // other options
        plugins: {
            dragData: {
                onDragStart: onDragStart
            }
        }
    }
    return (
      <Chart
        type="bar"
        options={options}
        data={data}
      />
    )
}
```

I'm sure the component is re-rendering, but still that function in particular is not. Other values in the options **are being updated**. For example:

```
    const options = {
        // other options
        plugins: {
            zoom: {
                wheel: {
                    enabled: activeState === "state_1" // This actually is being updated and works
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also tried with `useMemo` for the options object itself and more combinations as well, but as you may have figured I'm not yet very used to how hooks are working. If necessary I can also provide more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `chartjs-plugin-dragdata` registers events on inialization and doesn't update them later. You'd need to use `useRef` to get the current value.

```js
const { activeState } = useContext(CertainContext);

const ref = useRef('');
ref.current = activeState;

...

const options = {
  // other options
  plugins: {
      dragData: {
          onDragStart: () => {
            console.log(ref.current);
          },
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Using refs worked, thank you (forgot to accept the answer, sry)